# Pandas: Find empty/missing values and add them to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, row, addition

I have dataframe where column 1 should have all the values from 1 to 169. If a value doesnt exists, I'd like to add a new row to my dataframe which contains the said value (and some zeros).

I can't get the following code to work, even tho there are no errors:

```
for i in range(1,170):
    if i in df.col1 is False:
        df.loc[len(df)+1] = [i,0,0]
    else:
        continue
```

Any advices?

Comment: This line `if i in df.col1 is False:` is never `True` hence it never adds a new row, you should change it to `if any(df.col1.isin([i])) == False` this tests if the value is not in the column which will return a boolean series, and tests if any of the rows are false. Do you require the missing rows to be appended at the end of the df?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be better to do something like:

```
In [37]:
# create our test df, we have vales 1 to 9 in steps of 2
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.arange(1,10,2)})
df['b'] = np.NaN
df['c'] = np.NaN
df
Out[37]:
   a   b   c
0  1 NaN NaN
1  3 NaN NaN
2  5 NaN NaN
3  7 NaN NaN
4  9 NaN NaN
In [38]:
# now set the index to a, this allows us to reindex the values with optional fill value, then reset the index
df = df.set_index('a').reindex(index = np.arange(1,10), fill_value=0).reset_index()
df
Out[38]:
   a   b   c
0  1 NaN NaN
1  2   0   0
2  3 NaN NaN
3  4   0   0
4  5 NaN NaN
5  6   0   0
6  7 NaN NaN
7  8   0   0
8  9 NaN NaN
```

So just to explain the above:

```
In [40]:
# set the index to 'a', this allows us to reindex and fill missing values
df = df.set_index('a')
df
Out[40]:
    b   c
a        
1 NaN NaN
3 NaN NaN
5 NaN NaN
7 NaN NaN
9 NaN NaN
In [41]:
# now reindex and pass fill_value for the extra rows we want
df = df.reindex(index = np.arange(1,10), fill_value=0)
df
Out[41]:
    b   c
a        
1 NaN NaN
2   0   0
3 NaN NaN
4   0   0
5 NaN NaN
6   0   0
7 NaN NaN
8   0   0
9 NaN NaN
In [42]:
# now reset the index
df = df.reset_index()
df
Out[42]:
   a   b   c
0  1 NaN NaN
1  2   0   0
2  3 NaN NaN
3  4   0   0
4  5 NaN NaN
5  6   0   0
6  7 NaN NaN
7  8   0   0
8  9 NaN NaN
```

If you modified your loop to the following then it would work:

```
In [63]:

for i in range(1,10):
    if any(df.a.isin([i])) == False:
        df.loc[len(df)+1] = [i,0,0]
    else:
        continue
df
Out[63]:
   a   b   c
0  1 NaN NaN
1  3 NaN NaN
2  5 NaN NaN
3  7 NaN NaN
4  9 NaN NaN
6  2   0   0
7  4   0   0
8  6   0   0
9  8   0   0
```

**EDIT**

If you wanted the missing rows to appear at the end of the df then you could just create a temporary df with the full range of values and other columns set to zero and then filter this df based on the values that are missing in the other df and concatenate them:

```
In [70]:

df_missing = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.arange(10),'b':0,'c':0})
df_missing
Out[70]:
   a  b  c
0  0  0  0
1  1  0  0
2  2  0  0
3  3  0  0
4  4  0  0
5  5  0  0
6  6  0  0
7  7  0  0
8  8  0  0
9  9  0  0
In [73]:

df = pd.concat([df,df_missing[~df_missing.a.isin(df.a)]], ignore_index=True)
df
Out[73]:
   a   b   c
0  1 NaN NaN
1  3 NaN NaN
2  5 NaN NaN
3  7 NaN NaN
4  9 NaN NaN
5  0   0   0
6  2   0   0
7  4   0   0
8  6   0   0
9  8   0   0
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression `if i in df.col1 is False` always evaluates to false.  I think it is looking in the index.  Also I think you need to use `pandas.concat` in modern versions of pandas instead of assigning to `df.loc[]`.

I would recommend gathering all missing values in a list then concatenating them to the dataframe at the end.  For instance

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': range(5) + [i + 6 for i in range(5)], 'col2': range(10)})
>>> print df
   col1  col2
0     0     0
1     1     1
2     2     2
3     3     3
4     4     4
5     6     5
6     7     6
7     8     7
8     9     8
9    10     9
>>> to_add = []
>>> for i in range(11):
...     if i not in df.col1.values:
...         to_add.append([i, 0])
...     else:
...         continue
...        
>>> pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(to_add, columns=['col1', 'col2'])])
   col1  col2
0     0     0
1     1     1
2     2     2
3     3     3
4     4     4
5     6     5
6     7     6
7     8     7
8     9     8
9    10     9
0     5     0
```

I assume you don't care about the index values of the rows you add.